# Emulating Oracle flashback functionality

Tags: oracle, flashback

I'm considering going from Oracle Enterprise Edition (EE) to SE/SE1 but want to retain the flashback database and flashback table features from EE.

Does anyone know how to emulate these features in SE/SE1?

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe you should ask how to emulate the flashback database feature and the flashback table feature in SE/SE1

Answer (score 0):

You could try with replicating you changes to change tables. Dbvisit replicate could be of good value here. See [Real-time Oracle data and database replication](http://www.dbvisit.com/products/dbvisit_replicate_real_time_oracle_database_replication/) It is not a free tool but it saves a lot compared to running EE.

Comment: Backup prior to change and then restore when needed? Of course it isn't very convenient but still a viable option.